# Convert functional component to class component in React - invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm new with React and have seen Material-UI as a nice library, so I would like use the `dashboard template` in my project. [Here the source code from Material-UI library documentation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/dashboard/Dashboard.js)
But the question came to me, how can I change this functional component to class component to fit my project. I've tried something like below:

```html
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
          display: 'flex',
      },
      ...
}));
```

```html
export class DashboardDemo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        const { classes } = useStyles();
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
        const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
            setOpen(true);
        };
        const handleDrawerClose = () => {
            setOpen(false);
        };
        const fixedHeightPaper = clsx(classes.paper, classes.fixedHeight);

        return (HTML code here...)
    }
}
```

It shows an error. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: So please try like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about the long post. I made it shorter to read. Hope that my question is clear for you

Comment: You cannot use hooks in class-based components.  You can however make a "bridge" functional component (FC) that consumes the hook and then passes it down to a class as a prop.  However, at that point you might as well just use a FC.  What ***exactly*** are you trying to do?  Why do you think you need a class?  Classes and FC can coexist in the same project, classes just can't use hooks.

Comment: @zero298 Cause my other components are class-based. I would like to keep them same. Can you give an example of 'make a "bridge" functional component (FC) that consumes the hook and then passes it down to a class as a prop'?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use hooks in class-based components. You can however make a "bridge" functional component (FC) that consumes the hook and then passes it down to a class as a prop. However, at that point you might as well just use a FC.

Again, classes and FC can coexist in the same project.  They are tools in your toolbox and should be used at the appropriate time.

```js
const {useState, Component} = React;

class ClassCmp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const HookWrapper = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState("hello");

  return (
    <ClassCmp foo={foo} onClick={() => setFoo("world")}/>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <HookWrapper />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```